# Universal app for windows 10. how to trigger background task?

Tags: c#, notifications, win-universal-app, background-task

I need to trigger a background task from interactive toast notification by pressing action button. i don't know what i'm doing wrong. i'm able to register a task and see it in visual studio. even i can debug it (debuger jumps to MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask.Run function but argument IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance is empty object), clicking on a button never runs the task or at least debuger dosn't show it.

I'm registering a background task like this

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask";
builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

showing notification

```
ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
ScheduledToastNotification myToastNotificaton = new ScheduledToastNotification(this.myToastXml, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), 2);
myToastNotificaton .Id = "toast_54ahk36s";
toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(myToastNotificaton);
```

in app manifest

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Tasks.MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

in toast template xml action buttons are

```
<actions>
    <input id="message" type="text" placeholderContent="200" />
    <action activationType="background" content="Count" arguments="count" />
</actions>
```

background task itsetf

```
namespace Tasks
{
    public sealed class MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

i can't understand how specifying activationype="background" on a notification templates action button is relating to MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask task? i can't find relevant info on that.

somebody please share your knowledge. maybe you have a working example or smf. any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand how specifying activationype="background" on a
>   notification templates action button is relating to
>   MyToastNotificationBackgroundTask task? i can't find relevant info on
>   that.

The trigger type of the background task (ToastNotificationActionTrigger) is what connects the Toast action to the background task. When user taps the action, app looks for a background task with ToastNotificationActionTrigger trigger to and runs if it finds one.

I used your code but couldn't reproduce the problem, trigger works fine. My guess is that you have already registered a task with that name but without the correct trigger type (try unregister first) -or- you have a spelling issue in the toast xml (activationType field).

Comment: I guess you were right. at first i guess i was using SystemTrigger (copied from example). After i unregistered task and registred it once again everything works fine! Thanks man you've helped me a lot! Sadly i can't mark your answer as useful as i haven't earned 15 reputation points...

Comment: I was stuck with this problem for a while. Note that your registration of the background task WILL NOT TAKE EFFECT unless you run the registration code (in many examples, this is placed in the onLauched() method of the app), which means that you need to run the app in the foreground once before this registration takes place.